# Keep referer mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, referer

Please help with the following question.

There is domain1.com, domain2.com, domain3.com. With the help of organized htaccess redirects to domain.com. But in the apache logs for domain.com, I do not see the referer, since when domain1 or domain2 request came.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.domain\.com?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://domain.com/$1 [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^rss\.domain1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^contacts\.domain2\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^rss.domain1.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.google\.com" [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^contacts.domain2.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/www\.google\.com" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ / [R=302,L]
```